# My website inner pages are not crawling and indexed?

Tags: search-engine-indexing

My website is built with angular js. when i submitted sitemap only home page is indexed and remaining pages are not indexed. I already changed all my page urls # to #! . please suggest me .

Comment: Hash bang crawling URLs are deprecated and should not be used anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This strategy is not recommended at all.

If you want better result then have fully qualified proper URL.

I remember WIX had similar pattern URL and it was ugly and hard to rank.

So, in your situation, it's highly recommended to move to a solution where you can have proper URL